# Magento2: How to add multiple fields in single row in magento edit form

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, admin-panel

Help me to add the multiple fields in single row of magento 2 edit form `backend/admin..`

for example:

**I have two fields First name & Last Name which I want in same row.**

Answer (score 1):

You add like following

```
<container name="name_group">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="type" xsi:type="string">group</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="string">admin__control-grouped-date</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/components/group</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Monday</item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">220</item>
                    <item name="breakLine" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="scopeLabel" xsi:type="string">[STORE VIEW]</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <field name="first_name">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Full Name</item>
                        <item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="string">admin__field-first-name</item>
                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">230</item>
                        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>
                        <item name="scopeLabel" xsi:type="string">[STORE VIEW]</item>
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">first_name</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </field>
            <field name="last_name">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="string">admin__field-last-name</item>
                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">240</item>
                        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>
                        <item name="scopeLabel" xsi:type="string">[STORE VIEW]</item>
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">last_name</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </field>
        </container>
```

Comment: it does not work when I am adding input box and a button on same line..do you have any solution for that?