# How to add 2 input fields in one row using UI component

Tags: magento2, component, ui

I want to add 2 inputs field in one row using the UI component in my custom module.
The field is about telephone so I want to have 2 textboxes, 1 asking for country code and another asking for a telephone number.

Somewhat like the attached screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new container inside the fieldset.
Find a solution here:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/187755/14889